# How to calculate FDR and Power?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, false-discovery-rate

would anybody give details numerical example of FDR and power calculation? for example, there are p-values given, using these p-values calculate threshold using BH procedure. then calculate FDR and Power. I need complete example of all this. you may use this p-values = 0.010, 0.013, 0.014, 0.190, 0.350, 0.500, 0.630, 0.670, 0.750, 0.810

thanks

Comment: Your question (logic and language) is unclear.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using R and want use the method of Benjamini and Hochberg (1995) to control the FDR, then you can use:

```
FDR <- p.adjust(p, method="BH")
```

where $p$ is the vector of p-values to compute BH adjusted p-values. To control the FDR at any specified level, say 0.05, you choose those cases with FDR < 0.05 as discoveries.

Note that Benjamini and Hochberg never formulated their procedure in terms of adjusted p-values, but the above procedure is nevertheless exactly equivalent to their method.

It is impossible to calculate power from a set of p-values alone. Power can only be computed when you have some knowledge of the joint distribution of the p-values under the alternative hypothesis.

You also need to be aware that the usual definition of power does not apply to FDR because FDR is not designed to control the probability of rejection but rather than the rate of rejection. It is more usual to run a simulation to estimate the number of discoveries that can be made while controlling the FDR below a specified value.

Comment: What if I fit a model with 100 variables and want to drop the non-significant coefficients and refit the model to get more accurate values for the significant coefficients?
How do I apply the p-value adjustment then?

Answer (score 4):

Given your p-values

0.010, 0.013, 0.014, 0.0190, 0.350, 0.500, 0.630, 0.670, 0.750, 0.810

*Note that i changed 0.19 into 0.019 because it makes the example more interresting*

Say you'd use alpha=FDR=0.05 (FDR is part of hypothesis testing, and is not what you calculate, like p-values, but instead something that you select) and you correct this with the Bonferroni correction then you would be very strict and accept the null hypothesis ($H_0=$ no effect), or alternatively reject any effect, for everything of your ten p-values since everything has p-value above $\frac{0.05}{10}=0.005$.

However, often you do not have a single extremely low p-value and instead you see a couple of low p-values (which happen to become all insignificant because the Bonferroni correction is so extreme in searching for the situation in which only a single variable is significant).

The Benjamini–Hochberg procedure does not only look at single p-values, and will also consider the chances that multiple effects would occur (for which a milder correction can be applied than the Bonferroni correction). In this way you become less strict* and increase the statistical power (reduce chance false negative), yet you will not surpass the family wise error rate (you won't surpass this error rate since the Bonferroni is an extreme, and not optimal, correction, which leaves lots of room for improvement).

---

BENJAMINI HOCHBERG PROCEDURE

you test multiple hypotheses the group the chances of rejecting the null hypothesis of multiple variables together

- $H_1:$ for one variable we reject $H_0$,
- $H_2:$ for two variable we reject $H_0$,
- $H_3:$ for three variables we reject $H_0$,
- etc.

and choose the highest one of these grouped hypothesis if it is rejected

- step 1) you compare: $$\text{the first p-value $0.010$ with the corrected alpha $0.005 = 0.05 \cdot \frac{1}{10}$} $$ This is not significant.

  You don't see this 0.01 p-value as significant because the
  chances for finding this among 10 variables are not considered
  significant, since you use a corrected value $0.005 = 0.05 \cdot
     \frac{1}{10}$, then you move on to the next step.
- step 2) you compare $$\text{the second p-value $0.013$ with the corrected alpha $0.010 = 0.05 \cdot \frac{2}{10}$} $$ This is not significant.

  You look at the chances of finding *two* times a value of 0.013 and
  below. Now you don't need to compare with $0.005 = 0.05 \cdot
     \frac{1}{10}$ but instead with $0.01 = 0.05 \cdot \frac{2}{10}$. This
  is still not significant.
- step 3) you compare $$\text{the third p-value $0.014$ with the corrected alpha $0.015 = 0.05 \cdot \frac{3}{10}$} $$ This is significant.

  You consider this significant because, while the 0.010 p-value in 10 comparisons is not so 'special' for an alpha level of 0.05, the three times a 0.014 p-value in 10 comparisons is significant for an alpha level of 0.05.
- step 4) you compare $$\text{the fourth p-value $0.019$ with the corrected alpha $0.020 = 0.05 \cdot \frac{4}{10}$} $$ This is significant.

  You continue (with the BH you look for the maximum) and compare 0.019
  with $0.020 = 0.05 \cdot \frac{4}{10}$. This is also significant and
  you will use this instead of step 3 (you look for the maximum).
- step 5) you compare $$\text{the fifth p-value $0.35$ with the corrected alpha $0.025 = 0.05 \cdot \frac{5}{10}$} $$ This is not significant.
- step 6 and further) Also any other values, which are all above 0.05 won't be significant either since the maximum to compare with is $0.05 = 0.05 \cdot \frac{10}{10}$.

*This is the typical pattern. As you move up the adjusted alpha-value to compare with becomes higher (since the hypothesis of increasing number, multiple, significant variables becomes stronger). And sometimes you will see some groups (in this case the lowest three and lowest four p-values) turn out significant, but if you move higher up this won't hold much longer (unless you have a situation in which _all_ variables have high significance)*

---

You should take note of the conditions for the validity of the test (such as no correlation/dependence between variables) and use the approriate variants of this test. Also note that this (the BH procedure) controls the 'false discovery rate' and not the 'family wise error rate'.

---

*The problem of this strictness occurs when you search among many parameters of which you already suspect not all of them will have an effect. Each of these (extra/useless) parameters will reduce the strength of your test because the level of deciding significance decreases when the number of variables increases ($\alpha_{corrected} = \tfrac{\alpha}{n}$)

Comment: thank you for reply. I simply need easy formula to calculate FDR and power from given list of p-values. because i am facing problem to calculate FDR and Power from list of p-values.

Comment: FDR: You dont *calculate* FDR from p-values, you *select* FDR and then just decide which factors are considered significant or not. FDR is the rate that you allow your self to fail and this is *independent* of the p-values. What you might be able to do, although not very advisable, is calculate the FDR rate at which a particular hypothesis (with the associated p-value) would have been rejected.

Comment: Power: that is *impossible* to calculate from p-values (alone). p-values are (exactly) about type I (false pos) error. If $H_0$ is true after all, how likely are our results/measured effects (at which we falsely reject). It is not type II error (false neg). There is no direct relation between p-value and power. That means, given the same p-values, you can have varying power (depending on the experiment size, type of test, etc.).

Comment: @Martijn Weterings Hello, I just found your answer which is a bit confusing for me. why would you compare a corrected p value to a corrected alpha ? can you please look at this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399807/fdr-calculation-for-each-p-value/399818?noredirect=1#comment748996_399818

Comment: @Learner the alpha is corrected, the p-value is not.

Answer (score 2):

Usually Power is calculated using software, but if you want to do it by hand then this link explains it well:
https://www.moresteam.com/whitepapers/download/power-stat-test.pdf

Comment: thank you for reply. it does not give clear example with p-values. so that i can calucaulate BHq from p -value , then fdr and finally power.