# FDR calculation for each p value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, multiple-comparisons

I am trying to understand how FDR is calculated and what to understand from it. I selected R as language so the example is in R

Lets look at an example of 10 samples

```
df<- structure(list(Names = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 2L), .Label = c("Sample1", "Sample10", "Sample2", "Sample3", 
"Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", "Sample7", "Sample8", "Sample9"
), class = "factor"), p_value_1 = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.013, 
0.014, 0.019, 0.35, 0.5, 0.63)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

To calculate FDR values , one should use adjusted-p_value which I think is influenced by the size of the sample , how ? I don't know. One can calculate it based on different method for example

```
FDR <- p.adjust(df$p_value_1, method="fdr")
```

I came across a study which I cannot understand. is the following formula FDR?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**How to do the math**
To adjust for multiple comparisons using the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure for controlling the False Discovery Rate (FDR) of $\alpha$ on $m$ different tests ($m$ is *not* sample size):

1. Compute the *p*-value for each test.
2. Order the *p*-values from largest to smallest.
3. In the first (ordered) test ($i=1$), compare the *p­*-value to $\frac{\alpha\times(m+1–1)}{m}$ (if you are using, say, $p=P(|T|>|t|)$ for two-tailed tests, if using $p=P(T>|t|)$, then replace $\alpha$ with $\alpha/2$).
4. In the second test ($i=2$), compare the *p­*-value to $\frac{\alpha\times(m+1–2)}{m}$.
5. In the third test ($i=3$), compare the *p­*-value to $\frac{\alpha\times(m+1–3)}{m}$.
6. In the i<sup>th</sup> test, compare the *p­*-value to $\frac{\alpha\times(m+1–i)}{m}$.
7. Using Benjamini & Hochberg’s method, we reject **all tests** including and following the first test for which we reject the null hypothesis.

Adjusted *p*-values simply invert the above math to transform *p*, instead of alter the rejection threshold. So reject if $p \le \frac{\alpha (m+1–i)}{m}$ becomes reject if $\frac{mp}{(m+1–i)} \le \alpha$

**Important things to note about adjusted *p* values**

- Adjusted *p*-values can be computed as $>1$ which is incoherent, since *p*-values are supposed to be *probabilities*. These are typically reported simply as $1$.
- One **cannot** determine whether any given test is significant or not simply by looking at the adjusted *p*-values alone, since these decisions also depend on the ordering of the unadjusted *p*-values.
- `p.adjust()` for some reason has a arithmetic error relative to Benjamini & Hochberg: the first two adjusted *p* values it reports are always given the same value in my experience.

Comment: I want to accept and like your answer, however, I have some questions regarding your answer. 1- can you give an example how to calculate it? second what about the definition of null hypothesis? can you please explain that ? Please look at this manuscript https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346101?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @Learner Hi Learner... I will be happy to add a worked example, but it may be a few hours. I am indeed familiar with the article you cite, and have read it a few times. I am not sure I follow you about null hypotheses? If you have a question about what they are you should ask a new question! :)

Comment: can you at least explain what is T, what is m?

Comment: $m$ is the number of tests. $P(T>|t|)$ literally "the probability of observing some value of a *t* test statistic greater than or equal to the absolute value of $t$." $P(|T|>|t|)$ literally "the probability of observing some value of a *t* test statistic greater than or equal to the absolute value of $t$ or less than or equal to negative one time the absolute value of $t$." But *t* test statistics are just an example. FDR works for *any* group of hypothesis tests.

Comment: how can I calculate the probabilities with hand? you make me more confused than I should be!!!!!! Can you give an example of 5 p values ? lets say I have a group (control) and a group of treated of 5 patients, I obtain 5 p values. Now how can I calculate the FDR with hand ?

Comment: Is this the same as what you explained ? https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/benjamini-hochberg-procedure/